# Can I delete older systemd-private-md32* files in/var/tmp?

Tags: directory, systemd

I've just found these directories on my ubuntu PC. How do they come about?

```
/var/tmp/systemd-private-762c8e6ced154b18ac76720c2c05f2aa-colord.service-fcAgPb
/var/tmp/systemd-private-762c8e6ced154b18ac76720c2c05f2aa-rtkit-daemon.service-iVKzv4
/var/tmp/systemd-private-809e24ac9abd4087b9941b3590575e64-colord.service-KlzdX8
/var/tmp/systemd-private-809e24ac9abd4087b9941b3590575e64-rtkit-daemon.service-mNk1of
```

The directories each only contain another subdirectory `tmp` which is always empty.

I mean the filename is kind of self explanatory. *systemd* probably creates them and they have to do with an *rtkit* and *colord* services/demons.

But *why* does systemd create them? Are these services misconfigured?

Some of these directories are older. Some have a modification time of the last boot.

Can I delete them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the effects of a `PrivateTmp` setting in a service unit.  You will find that your `rtkit-daemon.service` and `colord.service` units employ that very setting.  For why *that* is, you will have to consult the people who wrote those service unit files.  `PrivateTmp` is after all a band-aid to cover over security holes left by the ways that some programs use `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` (excessively privileged use, failure to avoid symbolic link attacks, overwriting anybody's existing files, easily predictable names, excessively open permissions, and so forth).  Maybe the security hole has been fixed.

`PrivateTmp` is implemented, under the covers, by systemd creating a nonce directory under the target temporary directory, and then mounting it in place of the original as a private mount point seen only by the service process(es).

Leaving such directories lying around used to be a systemd bug, that people worked around with `tmpfiles.d` snippets of their own.  It is claimed to have been fixed in your version of systemd.  Of course, these directories *also* get left around by dirty shutdowns.

You can, of course, delete the ones that aren't currently being used by the relevant services.

## Further reading

- [*Accumulation of `/var/tmp/systemd-private-*` directories*](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=884344).  Fedora Bug #884344.
- Andrei Borzenkov (2015-02-23).  [*Maybe SOLUTION, re: back to the 'fix this eternally broken temp file cleanup service' debate*](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse/2015-02/msg00579.html).  OpenSUSE mailing list.

Comment: DIrty shutdowns, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the `systemd-private-*` directories go back to the date of installation. 1,313 directories to be precise.

```bsh
$ sudo ll /var/tmp/systemd* | wc -l

1313
```

---

### To see the oldest:

```bsh
$ sudo find /var/tmp/systemd*/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n | head -n10

1533569244.0956004300 Mon 06 Aug 2018 09:27:24 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-832d96941700493c839693111456977a-systemd-timesyncd.service-KcGCS0/
1533569244.0956004300 Mon 06 Aug 2018 09:27:24 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-832d96941700493c839693111456977a-systemd-timesyncd.service-KcGCS0/tmp
1533854792.8651238050 Thu 09 Aug 2018 04:46:32 PM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-8cbe510abc7145faad0ac1066893402d-systemd-timesyncd.service-kcbYN9/
1533854792.8651238050 Thu 09 Aug 2018 04:46:32 PM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-8cbe510abc7145faad0ac1066893402d-systemd-timesyncd.service-kcbYN9/tmp
1533854792.9731238090 Thu 09 Aug 2018 04:46:32 PM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-8cbe510abc7145faad0ac1066893402d-colord.service-wAL2zb/
1533854792.9731238090 Thu 09 Aug 2018 04:46:32 PM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-8cbe510abc7145faad0ac1066893402d-colord.service-wAL2zb/tmp
1533854797.7731240070 Thu 09 Aug 2018 04:46:37 PM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-8cbe510abc7145faad0ac1066893402d-rtkit-daemon.service-gWFNlM/
1533854797.7731240070 Thu 09 Aug 2018 04:46:37 PM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-8cbe510abc7145faad0ac1066893402d-rtkit-daemon.service-gWFNlM/tmp
1538476157.7205560490 Tue 02 Oct 2018 04:29:17 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-93ebca0a53c949e7ba1c49e225a5d366-systemd-timesyncd.service-ndLBbW/
1538476157.7205560490 Tue 02 Oct 2018 04:29:17 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-93ebca0a53c949e7ba1c49e225a5d366-systemd-timesyncd.service-ndLBbW/tmp
```

I suspend/resume twice a workday and a few times on holidays.I also do software development which can lead to system lockups. Inevitably after a week or so the system crashes. Systemd leaves behind 8 directories, 2 directories for each of these services:

- systemd-timesyncd.service
- colord.service
- rtkit-daemon.service
- fwupd.service

---

### To see the newest:

```bsh
$ sudo find /var/tmp/systemd*/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n10

1629682894.7751521600 Sun 22 Aug 2021 07:41:34 PM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e1e62fd4795745429b7b84e298dc220e-fwupd.service-OEmxk6/
1629682894.7751521600 Sun 22 Aug 2021 07:41:34 PM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e1e62fd4795745429b7b84e298dc220e-fwupd.service-OEmxk6/tmp
1631968966.2887179850 Sat 18 Sep 2021 06:42:46 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e0e32f86f4874cb0907775645f048900-systemd-timesyncd.service-cej24b/
1631968966.2887179850 Sat 18 Sep 2021 06:42:46 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e0e32f86f4874cb0907775645f048900-systemd-timesyncd.service-cej24b/tmp
1631968966.4487179920 Sat 18 Sep 2021 06:42:46 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e0e32f86f4874cb0907775645f048900-colord.service-kLXvIV/
1631968966.4487179920 Sat 18 Sep 2021 06:42:46 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e0e32f86f4874cb0907775645f048900-colord.service-kLXvIV/tmp
1631968972.2567182310 Sat 18 Sep 2021 06:42:52 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e0e32f86f4874cb0907775645f048900-rtkit-daemon.service-y3n0R5/
1631968972.2567182310 Sat 18 Sep 2021 06:42:52 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e0e32f86f4874cb0907775645f048900-rtkit-daemon.service-y3n0R5/tmp
1631968990.9967190020 Sat 18 Sep 2021 06:43:10 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e0e32f86f4874cb0907775645f048900-fwupd.service-ybbQ3L/
1631968990.9967190020 Sat 18 Sep 2021 06:43:10 AM MDT /var/tmp/systemd-private-e0e32f86f4874cb0907775645f048900-fwupd.service-ybbQ3L/tmp
```

Notice these are from September 18, 2021 which is the last boot time:

```bsh
$ uptime

 11:48:31 up 8 days,  5:05,  1 user,  load average: 0.60, 1.18, 1.25
```

---

### Zenity Scrollbox

Reviewing the listing in the terminal is time-consuming so using `zenity` is helpful:

```bsh
$ sudo find /var/tmp/systemd*/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n | zenity --text-info --title "Systemd files...$(uptime)" --width 1900 --height 900
```

[image: systemd private directories.png]

The final step will be to find directories older than last boot (8 days ago in my case) and piping output to `rm` command.